# Background transparency turn to black on Android

Tags: codenameone

I'm building a form as a menu, because the demand is a menu that come from the top. So I've build my form with a BoxLayout Y, set the backgroud transparency of to 0 with the theme and added a container with my menuItems inside. A Cover-Uncover transition to add some menu feeling and the form is complete.

On Ipad (cropped):
[image: On Ipad (cropped)]

The result is pretty good, but I have a big problem on Android : the transparency work during the transitions, but when the in transition is over, all the transparency turn to black. I've tried on Android 4.4.2 (old archos tablet) and on Android 8.0 (brand new P20 lite smartphone).

On Android while transition is active : 
[image]

On Android after transition
[image]

Is it a way to show the previous form on Android ? Or even a sidemenu swipable from the top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms can't have transparency. There is nothing behind them. If there was we'd need to keep in memory every form you ever showed because you could reference forms in code and set them to transparent on the fly. `Form` is a special case top level component when you show it, it's the end of the line.

You can accomplish this with a `Dialog` or an `InteractionDialog` both of which work similarly. In fact the side menu bar code is just an `InteractionDialog`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look to the SideMenuBar Code and recreate my menu with some inspiration from there.